# Can't Integrate Maven Into Eclipse via Plugin for Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm at my wits end trying to get Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.20150219-0708 to properly integrate with Maven. It's the standard EE edition you find on the eclipse.org site.

I have the following repos listed as "software sites" in my "install new software wizard", in addition to the standard ones.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

http://ifedorenko.github.com/m2e-extras/

http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/luna/1.1

I didn't cherry pick what plugin to install, instead I installed every single thing that came up from entering "maven" into the search box. The "contact all update sites during install to find required software" tick box is also checked.

I try to uninstall all these, but for most things the wizard tells me that it can't uninstall them because "other parts of the system need them". I think that most of these are already part of the core install or something. Uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything with "maven" in its name doesn't help.

I have restarted Eclipse, multiple times. Maven is also installed on my system, and I have the variables for it exported properly on my system and Maven works fine on its own.

No matter what I do I don't see any kind of integration whatsoever in Eclipse. I can't see a Maven menu in Preferences. I can't create a Maven project in the project explorer. I can't convert an existing project into a Maven one.

Comment: What version of Java are you using to run Eclipse? Can you share *anything* about the environment in which you're trying this?

Comment: @nitind debian wheezy linux is the OS. `java -version` returns
"1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.4) (6b27-1.12.4-1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: You need at least Java 7, preferably Java 8, to run modern releases of Eclipse.

Comment: @nitind Eclipse Luna was running absolutely fine, no complaints on my end except for said lack of integration. I managed to get Tomcat 8 running on it fine, made multiple Swing apps with it etc. 

I ended up just downloading Eclipse Kepler and transferring everything there. Not technically a solution to my exact question, but a rather tiring workaround.